# react firebase initializeApp is not defined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to use firebase storage on react app,
but I get a error that I dont know where is coming from

Line 15:15:  'initializeApp' is not defined

**This is my config.js File**

Thanks for help

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import 'firebase/storage';
import 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "//myapikey",
    authDomain: "//firebase name.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "//firebase name",
    storageBucket: "//firebase name.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "156082439629",
    appId: "//appid..."
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const projectStorage = firebase.storage();
const projectFirestore = firebase.firestore();

export {
    projectStorage,
    projectFirestore
};
```

Comment: What is your Firebase version ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj 9.6.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `compat` version of Firebase SDK then you would have to import compat version of other Firebase services too. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import 'firebase/compat/storage';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {...};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
// with firebase. namespace

const projectStorage = firebase.storage();
const projectFirestore = firebase.firestore();

export {
    projectStorage,
    projectFirestore
};
```

However, I would recommend using the [Modular SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) and initialize Firebase like this:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {...};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const projectStorage = getStorage();
const projectFirestore = getFirestore();

export {
    projectStorage,
    projectFirestore
};
```

Also checkout [Getting started with Firebase for the web](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQvOAnNvcNQ)

Comment: First of all , thank you , I used compat before to solve other error , but now I tried the SDK solution works great , Thanks